# Validate password length using an attribute that also accepts empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes, validation-application-bl

I would like to validate password length on edit **if password is entered** otherwise empty should be considered ok.

I have seen suggestions to skip the attribute for the password in the edit model and do the validation in the code, but I want to use attributes for all validation.

It seems like there should be something like this already in the library. Have I simply missed it?
I'm using EntLib 5 VAB and MVC 2 on AspNet 3.5.

Vanilla edit model:

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public class EditAccountModel
{
    public Guid ProviderUserKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //[ValidatePasswordLength] <- Requires password
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute` is not part of the MVC core, but is created within your project from the default MVC project template, in AccountModels.cs. You can freely modify its implementation. Change the `IsValid` method to accept `null` and the empty string as valid values.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value) {
    string valueAsString = value as string;
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString) || valueAsString.Length >= _minCharacters);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works with MVC4 and jQuery 1.8.

Requirement is Minimum 9 chars length, 1 special char and 1 digit and 1 Uppercase letter is mandatory in the password.

```
[DisplayName("Password")]
[RegularExpression(@"^.*(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*\(\)_\-+=]).*$", ErrorMessage = "User_Password_Expression")]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 9,  ErrorMessage = "length err")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public override sealed string Password { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new [custom validation attribute](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

```
Public Class MyCustomValidation : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
   public MyCustomValidation() : base([Your regular expression])
   {} 
}
```

And modify your code as below:

```
[MyCustomValidation(ErrorMessage = "")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[DisplayName("Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```